# Convert cURL request to Guzzle request

Tags: php, curl, request, behat, guzzle

I am trying to convert existing cURL request to Guzzle 6. The code for curl request is like this (wrote with sprintf function).

```
curl -F "uid=%s" -F "filehandle=@%s" %s 2>/dev/null
```

How can I convert this request to Guzzle approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one works for me - [link](https://github.com/Bergil32/docker-behat/commit/63510c60c5eb6fe7188f079c89e5a00b1317d8c8).